# Incorrect Output If then Else statement in R

Tags: r

Please see the code below. the code does not show the accurate value as everything it being set to "Others" in the new var titles:

```
extractTitle<- function(name){
  name<-as.character(name)

  if (length(grep("Miss.",name))>0){
    return("Miss.")
  }else if (length(grep("Master.",name))>0){
    return("Master.")
  }else if (length(grep("Mrs.",name))>0){
    return("Mrs.")
  }else if (length(grep("Mr.",name))>0){
    return("Mr.")
  }else {
    return("Other")
  }
}

titles<- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(data.combined)){
  titles<- c(titles,extractTitle(data.combined[i,"name"]))
}

data.combined$title<- as.factor(titles)
```

Kindly advice where is the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the `data.combined` used? Or part of it, preferably using `dput`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me when trying it with simple test data ("foobar", "fooMaster.bar" "Master.bar", "fooMaster.", etc.). So the issue probably lies with how you handle the dataset to the function. For example, if you misspelled the "name" column access this will handle NULL to the function, which in turn will cause "Other" be handed back.

PS: sorry for posting this as an answer but I'm still too low for comments :)